# grep for a particular text with special character

Tags: shell, grep

I am trying to grep a particular text in a log file but I am not able to get the particular text that I am interested

```
echo "[27 May 2019 23:42:32,418] [Accept-Nsh-Proxy-Thread] [ERROR] [::] [Appserver] Too many open files (Accept failed)" >> sl3737474646464-config_console.log | tail -f sl3737474646464-config_console.log
```

```
cat sl3737474646464-config_console.log | grep -i "\[Appserver\] Too many open files \(Accept failed\)"
```

But not able to get the string

How to get that text that I echoed?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` takes the `\(` as the beginning of the capture group. Just drop the `\` from `(` and `)`.

```
$ echo "[27 May 2019 23:42:32,418] [Accept-Nsh-Proxy-Thread] [ERROR] [::] [Appserver] Too many open files (Accept failed)" | grep -i "\[Appserver\] Too many open files (Accept failed)"
[27 May 2019 23:42:32,418] [Accept-Nsh-Proxy-Thread] [ERROR] [::] [Appserver] Too many open files (Accept failed)
```

Or use `grep -F` switch. It causes grep to parse the argument literally, so you can forget about escaping:

```
$ echo "[27 May 2019 23:42:32,418] [Accept-Nsh-Proxy-Thread] [ERROR] [::] [Appserver] Too many open files (Accept failed)" | grep -i -F "[Appserver] Too many open files (Accept failed)"
[27 May 2019 23:42:32,418] [Accept-Nsh-Proxy-Thread] [ERROR] [::] [Appserver] Too many open files (Accept failed)
```